# trigger number of files selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to catch the `number of files` user has selected using `JQuery` but my code does not work. ***JQuery is added and working***. Every time the alert box display 1.

```js
$('#product_image').change(function(){
   var size = $("#product_image").length;
   alert(size);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
         <input type="file" class="" id="product_image" name="product_image" multiple>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check length of [`files`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-files) property of the DOM element.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="file" class="" id="product_image" name="product_image" multiple>
</form>
JQuery
<script>
  $('#product_image').change(function() {
    var size = this.files.length;
    console.log(size);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `$(this).get(0).files.length`

```js
$('#product_image').change(function(){
   var size = $(this).get(0).files.length
  console.log(size);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
         <input type="file" class="" id="product_image" name="product_image" multiple>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking the length of the HTML Element and are not (as you actually intend to) checking the length of the files.

```
$('#product_image')[0].files.length  // returns the number of files in your input
```